# If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(B^{\circ})\subset (f^{-1}(B))^{\circ}$ for all $B\subset Y$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification

Why did I get = and not $\subset$ in this proof? Where is the mistake? I don't see it.

Let $(X,\tau),(Y,\rho)$ be topological spaces . If $f:X\to Y$  is continuous, then $f^{-1}(B^{\circ})\subset (f^{-1}(B))^{\circ},\forall B\subset Y.$ (where $^\circ$ denotes the interior).

Proof

As $f$ is continuous, then $\forall B\in\rho,f^{-1}(B)\in \tau$.

This implies that $(f^{-1}(B))^{\circ}=f^{-1}(B)$ and as $B\in\rho, B=B^\circ$.

Therefore $f^{-1}(B^{\circ})=f^{-1}(B)= (f^{-1}(B))^{\circ}$.

Comment: Why does $B$ have to be open?

Comment: @Randall because is in $\rho$ and all the elements of $\rho$ are open.

Comment: No, in your theorem. It never says "for all open sets $B$."  This makes the difference in your argument.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x^2$ which we will all agree is continuous in the ordinary topology.  Given $B= [0,1]$, we have $f^{-1}(B^\circ) = (-1,0) \cup (0,1)$.  Yet, $(f^{-1}(B))^\circ =[-1,1]^\circ = (-1,1)$ so you definitely can't have equality all the time.

In the event that $B$ is open, you are right.  However, the statement asserts the subset inclusion (not equality) for ALL subsets of $Y$, not just the open ones.

Comment: I understand,  and maybe it's not even correct because  what if $Y$ doesn't have open sets.

Comment: But due the characterization of continuity, it must have only open  and closed sets, so will the proof be correct and complete if I also consider $B\in C_X\implies f^{-1}(B)\in C_Y$? where $C_X$ is the collection of closed sets on X.

Comment: No:  you only need the fact that $A^\circ$ is the largest open set inside $A$, no matter if $A$ is open, closed, both, or neither.